# How to replace array keys with predefined values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

Assuming that I have following situation:

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(1 => "text1",2 => "text2", 3 => "Text3" , 4 => "Text4");
```

After some functions I receive a string which contains these values:

```
$string = "2,1,4,3"; // this values are dynamic
```

What I want to achieve is to sort that array (`$array`) in the string's order; so the result should be:

```
<--- some function --- > 
$result = array(2 => "text2",1=> "text1",4=>"Text4",3=>"Text3"));
```

Comment: Please don't tell me you are getting these dynamic values from a database.

Comment: no , this are randomly received by custom function .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `array_multisort()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Untested, but probably something like:

```
array_multisort(explode(",", $string), $array);
```

Keys may get lost though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$keyArr = explode(',', $string);
$sortedArr = array();

foreach ($keyArr as $key)
{
    $sortedArr[$key] = $array[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Break up the string into indexes with `explode`
2. Make an empty array `$result`
3. Iterate over the exploded array of keys, doing `$result[$key] = $input[$key]`

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/PQ58d)**.